# Is there a way to update multiples documents in MongoDB without providing the whole Object?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

I'm trying to save a bunch of documents at once using MongoTemplate, I've tried `updateMulti` but doesn't seem that it will work for me.

Here's an example:

```json
[
  {
    "personId": "A",
    "ranking": 1
  },
  {
    "personId": "B",
    "ranking": 2
  },
  {
    "personId": "C",
    "ranking": 3
  }
]
```

So then the client will reach the API and send me a list with the new Ranking positions:

```json
[
  {
    "personId": "Z",
    "ranking": 1
  },
  {
    "personId": "A",
    "ranking": 2
  },
  {
    "personId": "B",
    "ranking": 3
  }
]
```

The ways I've achieved the desired result was iterating trough the list and saving each entity at time, but since the list goes far beyond 3 entities, I think that is possible to save all at once, but couldn't find a suitable way.

The whole object is something like:

Person

```json
 {
    "personId": "A",
    "ranking": 1,
    "firstName": "foo",
    "lastName": "bar",
    "birth": "01/01/2010",
    "registered": "01/01/2020"
  }
```

Comment: can you post what you tried? and do you use MongoRepository as well?

Comment: I've tried to use the repository `saveAll(Iterable<S> var1)` but if I don't provide the whole object, the missing fields will be removed from the collection using this method.